# how to debug golang cobra cli app in vscode

Tags: go, vscode-debugger, go-cobra

I have a golang cobra cli app. have configured my vscode for debugging. I want to debug a specific command using vscode for my application.

I am using this launch.json

```
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${fileDirname}"
        }
```

If I select main.go and start debugging it just prints the help for my command. How can I debug a particular cli subcommand in vscode? Like say abc create or abc version

If I select a subcommand package and then debug it says : Failed to launch :could not launch process:not an executalbe file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the VSCode launch configuration to pass arguments using:

```json
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${fileDirname}"
            "args": ["arg1", ...]
        }
```

Note that you may prefer to write the path to your main go file in the `program` field so that you can run/debug no matter what file you are currently on.

Reference:

- launch.json: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes
- VSCode Variables: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference